# Need regular expression for the URL

Tags: javascript, regex, vb.net

I have a following regular expression in VB

```
(http[s]?|rtsp|qvmc|rtmp)://(([^/:\.[:space:]]+(\.[^/:\.[:space:]]+)*)|([0-9](\.[0-9]{3})))(:[0-9]+)?((/[^?#[:space:]]+)(\?[^#[:space:]]+)?(\#.+)?)?
```

and URL I have :

```
rtsp://root:admin@192.0.0.0/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&audio=1>rtsp_transport=udp_multicast>recordingfilename=c:\folder\recfile.mp4
```

Unable to pass match with the above regular expression, Can anyone suggest what is the mistake in Regular expression.

Comment: .NET regex engine does not support POSIX character classes. Try replacing all `[:space:]` with `\s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't have something to match the username and password before the @.
While your URL has a user and password, so it won't match.

And don't use a [POSIX character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) like `[:space:]` in .NET

This pattern will also capture the username and password:

```
(https?|rtsp|qvmc|rtmp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?:(\/[^\s?#]+)([?][^\s#]+)?)?([#]\S*)?
```

Comment: This didn't work for me . Actual issue that i am facing is matching **">"** character    ,This part gave error >rtsp_transport=udp_multicast .What modification should i do to match > character at the end of URL .

Comment: @PradeepKumar Could it be that you want to use that capture after the '?' in an XML?  In that case it could be that you need to replace those '>' by '&gt;'  [to keep the XML conform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents).

Comment: Also consider that sometimes you don't need a regex to get parts from a string.  For example, you could split a string like "?xxx>yyy>zzz" on ">" to get an array.

Comment: There's also the option to add `>` to the negative character class for what comes after the the `?`.  I.e. `[?][^\s#>]+`  Then the regex would match your example only till the `&audio=1` and ignores what comes after that.